# Haml, Ruby on Rails, How to populate table in order according to date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

sorry I was unsure of how to word my question in the title but basically I'm trying to iterate through the events and populate the table rows starting from the event date closest to today's date.

```
- @events.each do |event|
  - if event.date > DateTime.now.to_date
    %tr
      %td= event.name
      %td= event.description
      %td= event.date
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should order the events by date in descending order:

```
- @events.order(date: :desc).each do |event|
  %tr
   %td= event.name
   %td= event.description
   %td= event.date
```